# How to adopt Send and Sync for a struct with a dynamic member (future cannot be sent between threads safely)

Tags: asynchronous, rust, concurrency

Consider the following code which declares a trait with an `async` method using the `async-trait` crate.

```rust
use std::{io::Result, sync::Arc};

use async_trait::async_trait;
use tokio;

// A trait that describes a power source.
trait PowerSource {
    fn supply_power(&self) -> Result<()>;
}

// ElectricMotor implements PowerSource.
struct ElectricMotor {}

impl PowerSource for ElectricMotor {
    fn supply_power(&self) -> Result<()> {
        println!("ElectricMotor::supply_power");
        Ok(())
    }
}

// A trait that describes a vehicle
#[async_trait]
trait Vehicle {
    async fn drive(&self) -> Result<()>;
}

// An automobile has some kind of power source and implements Vehicle
struct Automobile {
    power_source: Arc<dyn PowerSource>,
}

#[async_trait]
impl Vehicle for Automobile {
    async fn drive(&self) -> Result<()> {
        self.power_source.supply_power()?;
        println!("Vehicle::Drive");
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let driver = ElectricMotor {};
    let controller = Automobile {
        power_source: Arc::new(driver),
    };

    controller.drive().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This doesn't compile with error "future cannot be sent between threads safely":

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:34:41
   |
34 |       async fn drive(&self) -> Result<()> {
   |  _________________________________________^
35 | |         self.power_source.supply_power()?;
36 | |         println!("Vehicle::Drive");
37 | |         Ok(())
38 | |     }
   | |_____^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
   = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn PowerSource + 'static)`
note: captured value is not `Send`
  --> src/main.rs:34:21
   |
34 |     async fn drive(&self) -> Result<()> {
   |                     ^^^^ has type `&Automobile` which is not `Send`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Future<Output = Result<(), std::io::Error>> + Send`

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:34:41
   |
34 |       async fn drive(&self) -> Result<()> {
   |  _________________________________________^
35 | |         self.power_source.supply_power()?;
36 | |         println!("Vehicle::Drive");
37 | |         Ok(())
38 | |     }
   | |_____^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
   = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn PowerSource + 'static)`
note: captured value is not `Send`
  --> src/main.rs:34:21
   |
34 |     async fn drive(&self) -> Result<()> {
   |                     ^^^^ has type `&Automobile` which is not `Send`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Future<Output = Result<(), std::io::Error>> + Send`
```

If I understand the error correctly, it thinks that `Automobile` is not `Send` because the `power_source` property is not and so it can't create a proper future. My understanding is that `Arc` is thread safe and implements `Send` and `Sync`, but I am still very new to Rust concurrency and still not completely clear on what that means.

How would I fix this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to modify your `Automobile` definition:

```rust
struct Automobile {
    power_source: Arc<dyn PowerSource>,
}
```

In rust a type is `Send` if and only if all its members are `Send` (unless you manually & unsafely implement `Send`). The same applies for `Sync`. So given that your `power_source` is not `Send`, then the generated `impl Future` will also not be `Send`.

[The way to fix it is to add a `Send + Sync` requirement for `power_source`:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71f332bdc067d829daa0fa947738ea1b)

```rust
struct Automobile {
    power_source: Arc<dyn PowerSource + Send + Sync>,
}
```

But why `Sync` you might ask ? The compiler is complaining only for `Send` after all. The reason it requires `Sync` is because [`Arc<T>` implements `Send` only if `T` is both `Send` **and** `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-Send)

##### Additional reading:

- [Send and Sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html)
- [A nice blog post about the same issue](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2019/10/11/AsyncAwait-Not-Send-Error-Improvements.html)

Comment: So simple once you learn to separate the trees from the forest. Thanks.